# Representability of the Lie algebra functor.

Tags: category-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

The lie algebra functor $T_1$ takes a Lie group to its lie algebra. I figure that this functor should be representable, since $T_1 \cong\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{LieGrp}}(\mathbf{R},-)$. Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, although I don't know why you'd call it the Lie group functor as opposed to the Lie algebra functor.

Comment: I agree. I find it odd that I couldn't find this result on google. One would expect it to be on wikipedia

Comment: To be fair, I personally don't know of any applications of this result. There are a lot of things that are true, but many of them aren't very useful.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, and many useful that are not true? :)

Comment: Well you immediately get a bunch of results that are true for representable functors in general, such as certain canonical isomorphisms. but even tho there might not be deeper implications, i find it worth knowing.

Comment: @Harry: I agree that these sorts of things are worth knowing, I'm just saying you shouldn't be surprised that you can't find this sort of thing by searching. Most people who do Lie theory just don't care about this statement because it's not that useful. (For example, it's true that you learn that the Lie algebra functor preserves limits, but the category of Lie groups doesn't have that many limits. It's already clear without this result that the Lie algebra functor sends finite products to finite products and that's good enough.)